# Why is the depthwise_conv2d implemented with the group parameter in Pytorch slower than Conv2d?

Tags: pytorch

After referring to the online materials, I used the following code to implement DepthWise_Conv2d under pytorch.

Using the summary test performance of torchinfo, I found that the running speed and the amount of process parameters are very huge.

**Depthwise_Con2d**

```
m = nn.Conv2d(16, 16, 3, stride=1, groups=16, dilation=1,bias=False)
n = nn.Conv2d(16, 33, 1, stride=1,  dilation=1, bias=False)
```

---

```
                    Name    Self CPU %      Self CPU   CPU total %     CPU total  CPU time avg       CPU Mem  Self CPU Mem    # of Calls

aten::mkldnn_convolution        90.40%      13.248ms        90.88%      13.318ms       6.659ms      17.59 Mb           0 b             2
         model_inference         8.38%       1.228ms        99.81%      14.627ms      14.627ms          -4 b     -17.59 Mb             1
             aten::empty         0.47%      69.400us         0.47%      69.400us      17.350us      17.59 Mb      17.59 Mb             4
      aten::_convolution         0.24%      35.000us        91.12%      13.353ms       6.677ms      17.59 Mb           0 b             2
            aten::conv2d         0.19%      27.900us        91.42%      13.397ms       6.699ms      17.59 Mb           0 b             2
             aten::zeros         0.12%      17.800us         0.19%      27.600us      27.600us           4 b           0 b             1
       aten::convolution         0.11%      16.200us        91.23%      13.369ms       6.685ms      17.59 Mb           0 b             2
       aten::as_strided_         0.07%      10.300us         0.07%      10.300us       5.150us           0 b           0 b             2
             aten::zero_         0.02%       2.600us         0.02%       2.600us       2.600us           0 b           0 b             1
```

---

Self CPU time total: 14.655ms

---

```
                    Layer (type:depth-idx)                   Output Shape              Param #
                    ├─Conv2d: 1-1                            [20, 16, 48, 98]          144
                    ├─Conv2d: 1-2                            [20, 33, 48, 98]          528
```

---

Total params: 672
Trainable params: 672
Non-trainable params: 0
Total mult-adds (M): 3.16

---

Input size (MB): 6.10
Forward/backward pass size (MB): 35.17
Params size (MB): 0.00
Estimated Total Size (MB): 41.28

---

**Conv2d Summary**

---

```
                    Name    Self CPU %      Self CPU   CPU total %     CPU total  CPU time avg       CPU Mem  Self CPU Mem    # of Calls

aten::mkldnn_convolution        90.64%       9.066ms        91.02%       9.104ms       9.104ms      11.84 Mb           0 b             1
         model_inference         8.16%     815.700us        99.71%       9.973ms       9.973ms          -4 b     -11.84 Mb             1
             aten::empty         0.44%      43.700us         0.44%      43.700us      14.567us      11.84 Mb      11.84 Mb             3
      aten::_convolution         0.23%      23.500us        91.25%       9.127ms       9.127ms      11.84 Mb           0 b             1
            aten::conv2d         0.19%      19.000us        91.53%       9.155ms       9.155ms      11.84 Mb           0 b             1
             aten::zeros         0.18%      18.100us         0.29%      28.900us      28.900us           4 b           0 b             1
       aten::convolution         0.09%       9.200us        91.34%       9.136ms       9.136ms      11.84 Mb           0 b             1
       aten::as_strided_         0.04%       4.000us         0.04%       4.000us       4.000us           0 b           0 b             1
             aten::zero_         0.03%       3.000us         0.03%       3.000us       3.000us           0 b           0 b             1
```

---

```
                    Layer (type:depth-idx)                   Output Shape              Param #
                    └─Conv2d: 0-1                            [20, 33, 48, 98]          4,785
```

Total params: 4,785
Trainable params: 4,785
Non-trainable params: 0
Total mult-adds (M): 22.35
Input size (MB): 6.10
Forward/backward pass size (MB): 23.69
Params size (MB): 0.02
Estimated Total Size (MB): 29.81

---

Could you tell me what went wrong?